# Windows 7 re-installation

Tags: windows-7, reinstall

I need to reinstall Windows 7 but the problem is that all my partitions are set to Dynamic disk type.Windows cannot install on Dynamic disc type partitions.During the installation process there is an option to format the drive but I cannot change the disc type.Is there any way to convert the partitions back into primary so that I can re-install Windows?
I am a complete fool.I don't even know why I converted the partition in which Windows was installed into dynamic type.
I have a 1TB HDD having 4 partitions and all of them are dynamic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you formatted the current installation? You can delete the partition and recreate them at the installation time. A simple [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+convert+dynamic+partition+to+primary+at+boot+time&oq=how+to+convert+dynamic+partition+to+primary+at+boot+time&aqs=chrome.0.57.30698&sugexp=chrome,mod=2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&biw=1280&bih=675&sclient=psy-ab&q=convert%20dynamic%20partition%20to%20primary%20windows%207&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=a4a3c475eb43e38f&bpcl=39314241&pf=p&pdl=300) will help you a lot about this.

Comment: If you have not formatted the current installation then you can convert it very easily. If you have formatted the current installation then you have to need backup your data if you want then download [Gparted live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) and boot from it and then delete all your partitions and recreate them.

Comment: So this is what I will do:
Use gParted to format all my partitions including C drive and delete all my Windows partition and then reboot and insert my Windows 7 installation disk. Windows will recognise my HDD as a single one without any dynamic disks. 
Is there anything else I need to know?

Comment: Ah! my apologies Gparted is for partition manger I mean for **Linux Live CD** if you have no access to your current OS. If you have then no need of gparted just follow the guides in Google search I refer you in above comment and then install the Window.

Comment: I can acess my OS. I am reinstalling the OS because I removed my graphics card driver and can't install any version(latest or old version) on it.The thing is that Windows will not install in a HDD that has a dynamic disk type partition. My C drive is dynamic. Hence unless I remove the C drive partition I cannot reinstall Windows on the HDD.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755238.aspx then use that tutorial. If you need anything else just ping me with @avirk and I'll be there to help if I could. :)